# Mongodb if object.key matches, sort documents by matched objects other key

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I've got these database documents in a collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e74"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.76 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.81 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e75"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.94 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.79 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e76"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.84 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.9 } }
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to sort the documents in the collection based on a query that asks:

Sort documents in the descending order of "values.scores", of label: male.

So the end results after the sort has to look like this;

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e75"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.94 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.79 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e76"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.84 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.9 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("629c1fc599a2c70018805e74"),
    "d&i": [
      { label: "male", values: { score: 0.76 } },
      { label: "female", values: { score: 0.81 } }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any ideas on how to form the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- filter the males
- get the max score for those males for each document
- sort by it descending
- remove the 2 temp fields that were added (you can add only 1 instead of 2, if nest more)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629c852191b564fc1e7e9593)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"maleScores": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$d&i", "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.label", "male"]}}}}},
 {"$set": {"maxMaleScore": {"$max": "$maleScores.values.score"}}},
 {"$sort": {"maxMaleScore": -1}},
 {"$unset": ["maleScores", "maxMaleScore"]}])
```